# HTML Divs does not come in two lines

Tags: html, css

I have referred many questions related to aligning `div` vertically and tried out various options including `float:left`, `display:block`, `clear:both` etc.  But nothing is giving the required solution.

Here is the complete code http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/8Db9A/3/ . If I keep the percentage as 98% for the div, it is working fine. Is there a solution to make it work with 80%?

Note: I am looking for a solution that does not use `clear`

[image]

CSS

```
    .errorMessageDiv
    {
        width: 80%;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        color: #56300a;
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px solid #b08b34;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: Dear sir, I couln't understand your problem, can you please add some more information? I just see a peace of code. What's the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8Db9A/6/ `filterElements {width: 90%;}`

Comment: What is your expected result? Just getting the rest of the text to the next line?

Comment: @Lijo Your problem is you haven't specified the widths of the containers, the error message is 80% so text (inline) will automatically want to go next to it, unless it has a set width. I gave it an arbitrary number (90%) so it doesn't want to fit into that ~20% hole

Comment: are you looking for that ? http://jsfiddle.net/8Db9A/9/

Comment: @MimiEAM Yes the result is as expected. What is your approach to reach at this?

Comment: @Andy Thanks I think, the `width` setting is the way to go for me. Can you please post it as an answer? I should be able to accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is trying to get on the same line as the error message because it is naturally "inline" and there is space that it can fit into. I would recommend setting a width to the form's container, big enough to not fit in the 20% hole. This forces it to a new line:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Db9A/10/

```
.filterElements {
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the form to show under the message div, you will have to add `clear: left` on the `.firstElement` div. Not on the `.errorMessageDiv` like you're doing at the moment

Comment: Uhm, clear is the solution... If you want to make it difficult for yourself, go ahead. However I don't see the problem with clear

Comment: Because you add clear to the element that needs to clear something. Not to the element that needs to be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

tho the question is kinda confusing i think you are looking those something like this 
I basically removed

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Db9A/9/